# What is this called? Polygon/Vertices/XY Points Related

Tags: c#, 2d, polygon, point, vertices

I am looking for the right term for this procedure:

Creating polygons with each point (x,y) generated through the application.
Example if I have this picture with this shape (white background is transparent)

[image]

the procedure or the application will create XY points in a way that it will define the points for example in the image where this shape can be extracted.

The shape is in final x,y points polygon shape (if points were to be connected it will look like):

[image]

I have tried googling different term but nothing was of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be after the [Convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). I.e. a convex polygon that fully contain your shape. There are some libraries for creating this on nuget, or ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

You could perhaps also use [Marching Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) if you need to extract the outline. But you could probably also just use the pixel coordinate of the border pixels if you do not need sub pixel precision.